# Missaligned QED in custom environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to place QED statements (`\qed`) inside of a custom environment of mine, but the squares get misaligned. Here's a picture of it:

[image: figure]

Here's the relevant code:

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]
    {
        \par\medskip
        \noindent \textbf{Exercício~#1.} \rmfamily
    }
    {
        \medskip
    }

% Some other code in here . . .

\begin{exercise}[7]
\begin{exitem}[a]
    ($\Rightarrow$) Seja $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Então $x \le y
    \Rightarrow x + \epsilon \le y + \epsilon$. Ainda, $0 < \epsilon
    \Rightarrow 0 \le \epsilon \Rightarrow x = x + 0 \le x + \epsilon \le y +
    \epsilon$.

    Pela arbitrariedade de $\epsilon$, $x \le y + \epsilon$, para qualquer
    $\epsilon > 0$. \qed

    ($\Leftarrow$) Suponhas que $x \le y + \epsilon$ para todo $\epsilon \in
    \mathbb{R}^+$ e que $x \nleq y$. Como $\le$ é ordem total, temos que
    $y < x$. Assim:

    \begin{equation*}
        \left \{
        \begin{aligned}
        0 & \le -x + y + \epsilon \\
        0 & < x - yA
        \end{aligned}
        \right .
        \Rightarrow
        0 \le (x - y)(-x + y + \epsilon) = -(x - y)^2 + \epsilon (x - y)
    \end{equation*}

    Tomando-se $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} (x - y)$ -- perceba que $y < x
    \Rightarrow 0 < x - y$ -- segue que:

    \begin{equation*}
        0 \le - \frac{(x - y)^2}{2} \Rightarrow (x - y)^2 \le 0
    \end{equation*}

    No entanto, $0 \le x - y \Rightarrow 0 < (x - y)^2 \le 0$ \lightning.
    Logo, $x \le y$. \qed
\end{exitem}
```

Is there anything I can do about it? How could I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Try this; immediately after any `\qed` that isn't flush right, add `{\parfillskip 0pt \par}`.  This should be just before a blank line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It worked! Is there any way I could bake this into the `\qed` macro (by redefining it)?

Comment: As son as I get an answer to the latter I'll post an answer to my question.

Comment: You don't say what document style or theorem package you're using.  It could make a difference.  Here's how `amsthm` defines `\qed`: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{\leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}`
I think that wouldn't be harmed by the addition of `{\parfillskip 0pt \par}` tacked onto the end, but I didn't try to test.  You could instead define a new `\QED` or `\myqed` if the robustness causes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the **@barbarabeeton**'s comments, this sould be fixed by post-pending `{\parfillskip 0pt \par}` to the misaligned `\qed`'s. This could be made into a macro:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\QED}
    {
        \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
        \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}{\parfillskip 0pt \par}
    }
```